# How to read/write a device's register connected to a gateway with pymodbus via TCP

Tags: python, serial-port, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I have to read and write a sensor using `pymodbus`. I'm not directly connected to the sensor, but I'm connected via TCP to a gateway and the gateway is connected via serial to the sensor.
I established a connection with the gateway in this way:

```
client = ModbusClient("192.168.127.254", 502)
connection = client.connect()
```

The connection with the gateway works because the socket is open. But I can't read from the sensor in this way:

```
if connection:
    request = client.read_holding_registers(0x00, 8, unit=1)
    data = validator(request)
    print(data)

    request = client.read_holding_registers(0x00, 8, unit=1)  
    data = validator(request)
    print(data)

    client.close()
```

How can I connect with the specify sensor connected to the gateway (id: 230, baud rate: 9600, parity: None, interface: RS-4852 wire)?

PS: The gateway is a *Moxa MGate MB3170*

Comment: Can you put on the output traceback?

Comment: Also please put on `.validator()` mehtod implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should know about your modbus slave register tables(your sensor)
 and know about it functions codes if read function code is `0x3` you should use `Read Holding Registers` and if function code is `0x4` you should use `Read Input Registers` functions

after that you should find your require register address , ex:temp register address is `0x05` and number of bytes is 2 and your sensor id is  230 and requirement function code is `0x3`

```
read_holding_registers(0x05 , 2, unit=230)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it but I didn't use properly the "unit" parameter. The code you provided works. So I just had to establish a TCP connection to the gateway and then specify the ID of the sensor as unit parameter in the reading function. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to make sure of connection between Gateway and Modbus device.

After, you can get data and test data registers by [modbus poll](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus_poll.html) application.

Whenever your connection is established, it's time to coding...

Comment: modbus poll is a good application if you are not a Linux user.